# Rails 3: include a field from has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through, nomethoderror

My model association is as follows:

```
#book model
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :recommendations, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :similars, :through => :recommendations, :conditions => ['recommendation_type IS NULL'], :order => 'recommendations.created_at DESC'

#recommendation model
class Recommendation < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :book
belongs_to :similar,  :class_name => 'Book', :foreign_key => 'similar_id'

#Books_controller -  injecting the recommendation_id
@book = Book.find(params[:id])
if params[:content_type]
  @content_type = params[:content_type];
else
  @content_type = "similars"
end

case @content_type

when "similars"
  # get the similars
  @book_content = @book.similars
  @book_content.each do |similar|
    @rec_id = Recommendation.where(:book_id=>similar.id, :recommendation_type=>'S').select('id').first.id
    similar << {:rec_id => @rec_id}
    # ^-- Above line gives NoMethodError (undefined method `<<' for #<Book:0x10de1f40>):
  end      

when "references"
  # get the references
  @book_content = @book.references
  @book_content.each do |reference|
    @rec_id = Recommendation.where(:book_id=>reference.id, :recommendation_type=>'R').select('id').first.id
    reference << {:rec_id => @rec_id}
    # ^-- Above line gives NoMethodError (undefined method `<<' for #<Book:0x10de1f40>): 
  end  
end
```

So as noted above, A book has many *similars* through *recommendations*. My requirement is that while retrieving *similars*, I would also like to **include the *id* of the corresponding record in the join table *recommendations*.**
My questions are:

- How can I include the field *recommendation_id* alongwith
  *similars*?
- If it cannot be included directly, then what is the correct way to
  determine this field separately (as shown above) and then
     inject it into the    *similars* instance variable so that I can use
     it directly in my views?

Comment: What are you trying to do here scope similars by recommendations? Add some more details and you'll get a better response.

Comment: @MatthewLehner, thanks for the comment. I Edited the post to inlude more details. Kindly help.

Comment: Can't you just use @similar.recommendation_id? - if that doesn't work, post your Similar model and the view logic you have in mind.

Comment: Also, the `NoMethodError` is because you're treating a `Similar` object as a hash or an array. You can't add attributes to an object on the fly.

Comment: @MatthewLehner, *Similars is not a Model!* it is :through *recommendations* model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you read the Rails guide on associations, specifically about the [has_many :through associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association).

A lot of your code doesn't make sense - for example:

```
@book_similars = Book.similars
```

This means you have a class method on the `Book` model for similars, but you don't mention it being defined, or what it returns. Rails just doesn't work like this.

Comment: I have modified the question to clarify the thing about the class method on Book model. It is being done simply through a case statement in the controller. Apologies for the confusion. My understanding of the  has_many :through associations is fairly clear for the task at hand. However my *original question* is to find a Rails way for including an attribute (Recommendation_ID) of the association table (recommendations) along with the data returned by the has_many :through. Note the belongs_to  of the recommendation table which is why .include (as suggested earlier) doesn't work